# using for loop to copy properties with an increasing value

Tags: powershell

I want to copy CustomAttributes from our Exchange Online account to the users AD object.

CustomAttributes 1-3 are to be copied to AD's ExtensionAttribute values (1-3)

I have created a script to automate this process.

```
  <following on from previous code>....  
    $ExtAttr= "ExtensionAttribute"
    $i =1
    $CustomAttr = ""

  For($i =1; $i -lt 4; $i++)
         {
           $CustomAttr = get-mailbox  $upn | Select CustomAttribute$i
           Set-ADUser -server Server -Identity $LocalADUser.SamAccountName -Add @{"$ExtAttr$i"=$CustomAttr."CustomAttribute$i"}
         }
```

This code works until I get to "$CustomAttr.CustomAttribute$i"

How can I amend this last part so that the CustomAttribute$i property copies the correct value based on what $i currently is?

So if $i is 1, then CustomAttribute1 should be copied to ExtensionAttribute1 for current select user in AD, for Si=2, then CustomAttribute2 to ExtensionAttribute2 etc.

Comment: Hi @sourmood, could you provide us with your error output or what its actually copying over? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The use of parenthesis and some string concatenation should fix this issue. Try replacing:

-Add @{"$ExtAttr$i"=$CustomAttr."CustomAttribute$i"}

With:

-Add @{"$ExtAttr$i"=$CustomAttr.$("CustomAttribute" + $i)}

Answer (score 0):

upon re-lauching the ISE and re-running this script. values are correctly copied across to the users AD object.

Sorry to waste your time